# supplying variables to class dynamically

Tags: python, saratoga

I have tried the example provided by official tutorial found here:

http://saratoga.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serviceclasses.html

I have made a few changes to the code and this is how it looks like:

```
http://23.21.167.60:8094/v1/yearlength?name=earth
```

My problem is that I need to provide the *account=211829* in the URL just like *name=earth*.

What I have written below is working because I have supplied the account number to the class. How do I do this dynamically?

```
import json
from saratoga.api import SaratogaAPI, DefaultServiceClass

class PlanetServiceClass(DefaultServiceClass):
    def __init__(self, myaccount):
        self.yearLength = {
            "earth": self.myquery(myaccount),
            "pluto": {"seconds": 7816176000}
        }

    def myquery(self, myaccount):
        import pandas as pd

        query = ('select * from mydata198 where account = %s  ')  % (myaccount)

        import sqlalchemy
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://dba:pass@1.2.3.4/test')
        conn = engine.raw_connection()

        df=pd.read_sql(query, conn)
        return df.to_json()

class PlanetAPI(object):
    class v1(object):
        def yearlength_GET(self, request, params):
            planetName = params["params"]["name"].lower()
            return self.yearLength.get(planetName)

APIDescription = json.load(open("planets.json"))
myAPI = SaratogaAPI(PlanetAPI, APIDescription, serviceClass=PlanetServiceClass('211829'))
myAPI.run(port=8094)
```

How do I pass the `account_num` variable from `PlanetAPI` class to `PlanetServiceClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to change your url to

```
http://23.21.167.60:8094/v1/yearlength?name=earth&account_num=12345
```

Then in the code you can access it via

```
account_num = params["params"]["account_num"]
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that you are currently using `account_num` to initialize the server before it is running. So you need to pass it in after it is running.

```
class PlanetAPI(object):
    class v1(object):
        def yearlength_GET(self, request, params):
            planetName = params["params"]["name"].lower()
            account_num = params["params"]["account_num"]

            mysql_result_json = self.myquery(account_num)
            self.yearLength['earth'] = mysql_result_json  # assign to earth if you want, as in your question
            return self.yearLength.get(planetName)
```

then change the rest of the code back to what it was in the tutorial:

```
myAPI = SaratogaAPI(PlanetAPI, APIDescription, serviceClass=PlanetServiceClass())
```

and

```
class PlanetServiceClass(DefaultServiceClass):
    def __init__(self):
```

Comment: and should I change myAPI to this ? serviceClass=PlanetServiceClass(account_num)

Comment: ok updated the answer. You need to assign `account_num` at "request" time, not server initialization time.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But it works only if I copy the myquery function in both the classes. Why?

Comment: Because the function isn't global. You need to use dot notation to access the object within the correct object. http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5170307264a7402d9a0012f5